# What is the use of -q parameter in grep command?

Tags: grep

```bash
echo "$password" | grep -q [A-Z]
```

What does `-q` do in this command?

Comment: It would help if you explain which *exact* parts of the documentation you don't understand. That makes it easier for answerers to tailor the answer to your specific needs.

Answer (score 5):

`-q` tells `grep` to exit with a success exit status as soon as one line matching the pattern is found and with failure if no matching line has been found in any of the inputs, and otherwise doesn't print anything on standard output.

It's usually used in conditions as in:

```
if grep -q foo file; then
  echo file contains foo
fi
```

Or:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q foo {} \; \
               -exec printf '"%s" contains foo\n' {} \;
```

Or:

```
<"$file" grep -q -xFe "$expected_line" ||
  die "Expected line not found in $file"
```

Here, your code sample is wrong for several reasons though:

- `[A-Z]` is also a shell glob operator, so should be quoted so that a `[A-Z]` argument be passed literally to `grep`. For instance, if there were files called `A`, `Z` and `X` in the current directory, the shell would expand the `[A-Z]` into those, so you'd end up running `grep -q A X Z` which looks for `A` in the `X` and `Z` files.
- What the `[A-Z]` pattern matches on varies with the locale and is often more or less random. To match on either of the `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` letters as is often intended by people who use `[A-Z]`, you need `[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]`.
- `echo` can't be used to output arbitrary data as depending on the implementation, it mangles strings that contain backslashes and/or start with `-`.
- also note that if the input is not text, the behaviour of `grep` is unspecified, so you may want to check first that the contents of `$password` is valid text in the user's locale.

So here:

```
if
  printf '%s\n' "$password" | grep -q '[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]'
then
  echo the password contains at least one ASCII uppercase letter
fi
```

Or:

```
if
  printf '%s\n' "$password" | grep -q '[[:upper:]]'
then
  echo "the password contains at least one letter considered uppercase in the user's locale"
fi
```

Would be more correct. Though in POSIX shells, you don't need `grep`, you can just do:

```
case $password in
  (*[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]*) echo contains ASCII uppercase;;
  (*[[:upper:]]*) echo no ASCII uppercase, but some other uppercase;;
  (*) echo no uppercase;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

-q, --quiet, --silent

Suppresses the normal outputs. The search ends immediately after the first hit and returns zero status even if errors occur.